# Trying to set a variable by a command. But keep getting an error

Tags: string, discord, discord.js

```
let comand = "!setvariable"
  if (message.content.startsWith(komut313)){
    let member = message.member
    if (member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
      const args = message.content.slice(comand.length).trim().split(' ');
      console.log(args)
       if (args === ''){
         message.channel.send("string is empty")
        }else{
         message.channel.send(args)
      }
    }
  }
```

What I am trying to do here is send a message if "args" is an empty string, if not then send the "args" in the channel.

But it says: "Can't send an empty message."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `args` is an array (as you used the `.split(' ')` method) and you can only send strings or [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)s.

Also, the `args === ''` will only check if `args` is an empty string.

You can either `join()` the array back to a string and send it or use `message.content.slice(comand.length).trim()`:

```js
message.channel.send(args.join(' '))
```

Chances are you never really wanted to create an array and only wanted to remove the command from it:

```js
if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
  const args = message.content.slice(command.length).trim();

  if (!args) {
    message.channel.send('string is empty');
  } else {
    message.channel.send(args);
  }
}
```